# Create simple site password for Rails - no username

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to protect a site with a very simple password only validation when user first visits site.  I currently use http authentication, but that requires a username & password.  I can hardcode password in back end.  Basics of site: local sports league where we keep our stats and info about league.  Simply trying to keep "riff-raff" out :)
I am a ruby on rails newbie, and am using this site as a way to learn.  Any help out there would be appreciated!

Comment: Interesting use case. Do you have a `User` (or some equivalent) model backing your authentication or you trying to bypass a user-based implementation entirely?

Comment: Trying to bypass user implementation entirely.  For now that is overkill.  There is no User model.

Comment: What's wrong with http basic auth then if you're using it? It seems it fits to your case.

Comment: Mostly I would like to remove the Username requirement.  The http basic auth doesn't work great on mobile, and I assumed a simple form with a text field could prove easier on a phone.

Comment: @SeanBleything any luck?

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something cookie-based.

In your `ApplicationController`, you'd implement a method for determining if the cookie is present that states that the visitor has entered your password – if the cookie isn't present, then you'll redirect to your password page:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def require_password_verification
    unless cookies[:visitor_password_verified]
      return redirect_to <whatever your passwords#new path is>
    end
  end

end
```

The controller for your password page would look something like this:

```
class PasswordController < ApplicationController
  def new
    # Nothing needed here because all your #new view needs is a password field
  end

  def create
    unless params[:password].present?
      return redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path, alert: 'Password is required.')
    end

    if params[:password] == Rails.configuration.visitor_password
      cookies[:visitor_password_verified] = true
      redirect_to(root_path, notice: 'Password verified.')
    else
      cookies.delete(:visitor_password_verified)
      redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path, alert: 'You've entered the wrong password.')
    end
  end
end
```

Your password would be stored in the `application.rb` file, like so:

```
config.visitor_password = '12345'
```

Normally, you would never store a password in this way because it's not secure at all but considering your use case, it's probably fine, since having a single password for everybody is already not secure.  However, if you did want to step up the security a notch, I would recommend storing your password in an environment variable, and then you could set the password like so:

```
config.visitor_password = ENV['VISITOR_PASSWORD']
```

That way, at least your password isn't hard-coded and accessible to anybody who looks at your, assumedly public, repo.

And then you can require the "password has been entered" cookie for whatever views you want like so:

```
class LeagueStatsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :require_password_verification

  def index
    # Whatever
  end
end
```

If somebody hits your `league_stats#index` page, then it's going to check to make sure the `visitor_password_verified` cookie is present and true first. If it is, then they'll get through to the view. If it's not, they'll be redirected to your `passwords#new` page.